# How can I get a future compose from query of various futures?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I need to get some articles from various url, so I did an async method to recover the articles of an url and a method to recover all the articles from all the urls.

**Pseudocode**

```
//Fetch all articles of al urls
Future<List<Article>> fetchArticles() async {
  var urls = ['http:/url.com/1','http:/url.com/2',...];
  Future<List<Article>> futureArts = Future.value(List<Article>(0));

  for (var url in urls) {
    Future<List<Article> futureArticles = fetchArticles(url);
    //join some way Future<List<Articles>
    //futureArts.add...¿?¿?
  }
  return new Future.value(List<Article>(0));//??
}

//Fetch articles from one url
Future<List<Article>> fetchArticles(String url) async {
  var page = loadUrl(url); 
  ...
  return parseArticles();
}
```

Is there a way of doing this or should I change the point of view of this solution?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking, especially since you have two functions named `fetchArticles`.  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with `Future.value`; that that just creates an already-completed `Future`.  Assuming that you want to wait for a multiple `Future`s to complete, use [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html).

Comment: Maybe there is another way to aproach this, but i trying to fetch all articles from various url (method1) and for that I'am calling a fetchArticle(url) for getting the articles from a specific url (method2). Method1 should join futures if it is possible from method2 or I need to find out another way of doing this.

Comment: Does `Future.wait` not do what you want?  BTW, Dart does not allow overloaded functions, so unless one of your `fetchArticles` functions is a class or instance method, you cannot have both.

Comment: I can't not test it right now, but It looks promising for what `Future.wait` description says. Thanks I'll try!